# How to send OK 200 response to TinkoffPayments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this POST method which recieves notifications from TinkoffPayments API and now I'm returning `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` but Tinkoff does not recive status OK 200 response.
Here is how they advice to make this response in their documentation

```
@POST
@Path("/ok")
public Response NotifyResponse() {
    return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
}
```

But I'm not like a pro programmer, I don't know how to make proper analogy in asp.net.
I've tried to make returned value of my method `IActionResult` and returning Ok("OK"). I've tried to asigning values to `HttpContext.Response` but nothing works. Tinkoff always shows this error in tests: `"Notification Error: we don't receive answer "OK" for next notification requests: CONFIRMED. Check and fix notification management: CONFIRMED. Then try test case again"` What can be the problem?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> New()
        {
            string t1 = "";
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
                t1 = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e){}

         BotContext _dbContext = new BotContext(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString"));

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        try
        {
            TinkoffNotification tn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TinkoffNotification>(t1);

            notification.Amount = tn.Amount;
            notification.Status = tn.Status;
            notification.OrderId = tn.OrderId;
            notification.PaymentId = tn.PaymentId;
            notification.Pan = tn.Pan;
            notification.RebillId = tn.RebillId;
            notification.Amount = tn.Amount;
            notification.CardId = tn.CardId;
        }
        catch{}
        try
        {
            _dbContext.Notifications.Add(not);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            _dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch { }

        HttpResponseMessage ht = new HttpResponseMessage();
        ht.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        ht.Content = JsonContent.Create("OK");
        ht.ReasonPhrase = "OK";
        return ht;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what language that example is written in, but it looks like you just need `return Ok("OK");`?

Comment: How about using something like Fiddler4, and seeing exactly what content does work and what doesn't.

Comment: It's talking about `notification requests: CONFIRMED`, while your action is named `New`. Might that be a thing?

Comment: In the Tinkoff account settings there is a field "notifications URI" and only one. So, I suppose I need to have only one method to manage all notifications. And there are a lot of different statuses in notifications like "CONFIRMED", "REJECTED" etc. So, I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neil's advice to use fiddler realy helped.Tinkoff actually wanted to Respond.Body to be "OK", not just standart respond 200 OK. And when I wrote "OK" earlier to the Body they did not accepted it because I hadn't set ContentLength and my actual Request.Body was something like that:

```
2
OK
0
```

Using fiddler helped to understand this.
So, this code works

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> New()
...
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body);
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response.ContentLength = 2;
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            await sw.WriteAsync("OK");   
            await sw.FlushAsync();
return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be returning an `HttpResponseMessage`, as that is a lower level construct.  Change the return type to `Task<IActionResult>` and return an `OK` object.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> New()
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the same thing? What about the `OK` text?

Comment: You can put `return Ok("OK")` if you prefer, but unless it's actually required, generally the 200 OK is enough.

Comment: Well that depends on what their API is expecting. I'm just going off their example code.

Comment: And the error OP is getting from them seems to suggest exactly that.

Comment: I don't think I should use an 'HttpResponseMessage' too. But I've tried returning ActionResult Ok() and Ok("OK") and nothing worked. So I'm looking for any other solution with almost dead hope that something would actually work.

Comment: If Ok("OK") isnt working then I'd suggest the problem is not at your end.   As I suggested earlier, use something like fiddler to examine EXACTLY what is being sent back from your app.

Comment: thanks for advice, I'll try that